# Error setting up MNN module in a Raspberry pi 4 "dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_libMNN)"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, .so

**My goal is to run my model.mnn in a raspberry pi 4**

1. It's all setup, just module MNN missing
2. Running python 3.7.3 and Respbian
3. I follow this tutorial with success: https://qengineering.eu/install-mnn-on-raspberry-pi-4.html
4. I have my libMNN.so file, but when I try to run in my .py its says:

   import libMNN as MNN
   ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_libMNN)

Answer (score 0):

Initial MNN targets mobile devices, hence it works with C++, being the fastest language for these devices. The installation at [Q-engineering](https://qengineering.eu/install-mnn-on-raspberry-pi-4.html) works with this C++ interface and will not working in Python.
MNN has a separate Python interface. Installation instructions can be found [here](https://www.yuque.com/mnn/en/usage_in_python).